# Is there a way in F# to write a generic function that will accept either a Tuple or Single value?

Tags: generics, f#, tuples, operator-overloading

I am writing some code to process a large data file. The CSV TypeProvider will return NaN for a given value if the field is none. I have quite a few fields, so it's cleaner if I write a helper function to check for that NaN and return a None instead. Not knowing how to write a more generic helper function, I came up with this:

```
let (!?) x = if Double.IsNaN(x) then None else Some (decimal x)
let (!?) (x, y) = 
    match (x, y) with
    | (x, y) when not(Double.IsNaN(x)) && not (Double.IsNaN(y))  -> Some (decimal x, decimal y)
    | (_, _) -> None
```

Unfortunately, my attempt to operator overload is not working correctly and duplicating code isn't great either. A newbie asks, is there a better way to do this?

(I am aware of something like PreferOptionals, but I need to do this more selectively)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make them static members of an intermediate type:

```
open System

type T = T with
    static member ($) (T, x) = if Double.IsNaN(x) then None else Some (decimal x)
    static member ($) (T,(x, y)) = 
        match (x, y) with
        | (x, y) when not(Double.IsNaN(x)) && not (Double.IsNaN(y))  -> Some (decimal x, decimal y)
        | (_, _) -> None

let inline parse x = T $ x


// Usage

let a = parse (1. , 2.)
// val a : (decimal * decimal) option = Some (1M, 2M)

let b = parse 1.
// val b : decimal option = Some 1M
```

Also note that it's better to use a binary operator to send also the intermediate type. This way you delay overload resolution.

You can also use named functions but it's more verbose.

**EDIT** Regarding delaying overload resolution.

First of all, I said in order to write it as a named function you have to write the constraints by hand:

```
let inline parse (x: ^a) =
    ((^b or ^a) : (static member ($) : ^b -> ^a -> _) T,x)
```

Note that the other answer that was later added is exactly the same as this, the only difference is that it uses a name `ToOption` for the static member instead of an operator.

Ok, now let's try to get rid of `T`, we can do it to some extent:

```
type T = T with
    static member ($) x = if Double.IsNaN(x) then None else Some (decimal x)
    static member ($) ((x, y)) = 
        match (x, y) with
        | (x, y) when not(Double.IsNaN(x)) && not (Double.IsNaN(y))  -> Some (decimal x, decimal y)
        | (_, _) -> None

let inline parse (x: ^a) =
    let call (_:'b) = ((^b or ^a) : (static member ($) : ^a -> _) x)
    call T
```

Note that I had to create a way to unify `^b` with `T`, that's why I added a `call` function.

Now this still works and it's a valid solution which cleans up the overload signature and add some more noise in the parse function, which in many scenarios is a good trade-off. But what if I remove completely the `^a` parameter from the trait call?

```
let inline parse (x: ^a) =
    let call (_:'b) = (^b : (static member ($) : ^a -> _) x)
    call T
```

this fails with

```
~vs6086.fsx(11,27): error FS0043: A unique overload for method 'op_Dollar' could not be determined based on type information prior to this program point. A type annotation may be needed.

Known return type: 'b

Known type parameter: <  ^a >

Candidates:
 - static member T.( $ ) : (float * float) -> (decimal * decimal) option
 - static member T.( $ ) : x:float -> decimal option
```

Why is that?

Because now the F# compiler knows at the trait-call site all the type variables involved.

Before this last change `^a`  was unknown and `^b` was unified with `T`, but since the other one was unknown, overload resolution was delayed to each future individual call of the `parse` function, which is doable since it's declared inline.

By knowing all type parameters, it tries to apply standard .Net overloading resolution and fails because there are 2 candidates.

Hope this explanation makes sense.

Comment: This is an incredibly helpful answer, but can you explain why delaying the overload resolution is beneficial?

Comment: I added an edit with an extensive explanation with sample code.

Comment: @lithiumfrost I think this should be remarked as the answer. There's a lot of good info in it.

Comment: @Asti Recommendation accepted! I am still trying to get my head around this, but the additional information and examples were super helpful.

Answer (score 4):

An F# binding has a single definition. Defining it again simply shadows the previous definition.

```
let f x = x
let f x = x * x //previous f is now shadowed
```

Here's a way to use statically resolved types to achieve the same result.
We're defining the members on an intermediate type (a single-case DU) called `Converter`:

```
type Converter = Converter with
    static member ToOption (_ : Converter, value) = 
        if Double.IsNaN(value) then None else Some(value)

    static member ToOption (_ : Converter, (x, y)) = 
        if Double.IsNaN(x) || Double.IsNaN(y) then None else Some(x, y)

let inline (!?) (x : ^a) =
    ((^b or ^a) : (static member ToOption : ^b * ^a -> _) (Converter, x))
```

Comment: I thought maybe F# would support function overloading for different signatures like C# supports method overloading. Helpful to know that it shadows instead. I am not clear on what is happening with the inline function definition, though. The function signature specifies a single parameter of type ^a, but the signature body uses ^b. Where does that come from?

Comment: F# has overloading for member functions (same as C#, but not for bindings). ^b is a 'hat type' - F# doesn't resolve extension methods in static resolved type bindings. So we use an extra type `Converter` here - you'll notice that the `ToOption` function signature is actually `ToOption(Converter, argument)` - we use that to locate the type where our functions are actually defined. It's a bit roundabout.